# Nginx + Pretty Permalink issue

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I am having an issue with WP pretty permalink and my nginx conf.

- Homepage works good
- Post = 404
- WP-Admin = 404

Can you help me to resolve it?

Relevant nginx configuration (excludes ssl, gzip, headers, etc.):

```
server {

  server_name sampledomain.com;
  listen 443 ssl http2;

  root /var/www/sampledomain/;
  index index.php;

  ...

  location ~ \.php$ {

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you copy/paste your conf into your question? For me, that link is blocked by corporate firewall. And, if the link ever goes down, it'd be helpful to have copied here to help people in the future.

Comment: Sorry but i can't (stackoverflow limitation). Another link: https://paste.ee/p/z50VS

Comment: That link blocked by my firewall as well. Here's an example of a site I host behind nginx that works properly if it's helpful to compare with your config. Good luck! https://github.com/collinbarrett/wp-host-on-containers/blob/master/nginx/conf.d/wp-collinmbarrett_com.conf

Comment: Thanks a lot i'll take a look. 

Here is mine: 
https://github.com/stonedb00/stonedb/blob/master/nginx

Can you take a look too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your config [here](https://github.com/stonedb00/stonedb/blob/2dd01acc0ea19e4ca09f66a3fa2f8ae5718f1571/nginx), I think you need to add another `location` block at or before line 39.

> For nginx, a web server aimed at high concurrency, high performance
>   and low memory usage, add the following location block within the
>   server block:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

via [WordPress Docs](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/#using-pretty-permalinks)

Example:

```
server {

  server_name sampledomain.com;
  listen 443 ssl http2;

  root /var/www/sampledomain/;
  index index.php;

  ...

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you don't mind, click the check mark in the top left corner of my answer to mark as working.